# Static files in Linux with Nginx

Tags: html, nginx, centos, http-status-code-404

Hello I am trying to upload static html files in Centos. So far I created subdomain and set nginx to open specific static html when It gets hit by browser. So far so good, problem is when I try to navigate from that static html to another html with relative paths say 
     Go elsewhere 
it does not work. I get redirected to my whateveraddress/differentFolder/index.html but nginx says 404 Not Found. Is there a way to be able to redirect to another pages within the html files or I have to register every route in   nginx?

```
nginx config:
server {
listen        80;
server_name   domain.tk www.domain.tk;
    root /home/apps/html/one;
    location / {
    index index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your nginx config to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after reading nginx documentation, it was to construct nginx.config like so:

```
server {
listen        80;
server_name   mydomain.tk www.mydomain.tk;
    root /home/apps/html;
    location /one/ {index index.html;}
    location /two/ {index index.html;}
}
```

The thing is what if, I have 100 posible routes, this way I must specify all in the config?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few different ways to do this, but one option is to use the NGINX [map directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html), as the example below, adding additional URI locations to the map block and leaving the server block untouched.

```
map $uri $index_uri {
  ~/one $1;
  ~/two $1;
}

server {
listen        80;
server_name   mydomain.tk www.mydomain.tk;
    root /home/apps/html;
    location /$index_uri {index index.html;}
}
```